# Waking up an app remotely, say from a bluetooth device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, bluetooth

1. Can we receive any notification from a bluetooth device, even if our app is in background?
2. Is it possible to launch an iphone app by sending some commands from a bluetooth device?
3. Is it possible to wake an app which is running in the background in similar way?

**UPDATED**

Apple says this in ***App States and Multitasking*** part of ***iOS App Programming Guide***

> **Communicating with an External Accessory**
>
> Apps that work with external accessories can ask to be woken up if the
>   accessory delivers an update when the app is suspended. This support
>   is important for some types of accessories that deliver data at
>   regular intervals, such as heart-rate monitors. When an app includes
>   the UIBackgroundModes key with the external-accessory value in its
>   Info.plist file, the external accessory framework keeps open any
>   active sessions for the corresponding accessories. (In iOS 4 and
>   earlier, these sessions are closed automatically when the app is
>   suspended.) In addition, new data arriving from the accessory causes
>   the system to wake up the app to process that data. The system also
>   wakes up the app to process accessory connection and disconnection
>   notifications.

What does it means? 
 Can we use remote control events to achieve what i asked above *ie* Waking up an app from background. or is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No this is not possible
2. No this is not possible
3. No this is not possible

Unless you jailbreak the device.

UPDATE after EDIT:
No this is not possible.

As was pointed out in the comments, this is straying towards the MFi territory. I suggest you search around the documentation a bit more.

Comment: Hi Nick, I read that iOS supports Voip services in background run, So my question is, can we tamper a play/pause message which is send to the  iphone from a BT remote to do something else

Comment: No. If you say your app supports VoIP and it doesn't, Apple will ban it.

Comment: Apple says this, Apps that work with external accessories can ask to be woken up if the accessory delivers an update when the app is suspended ..What does it means?

Comment: Just a note: this debate is very close to MFi NDA

Comment: @Krrish This is straying from your original question now. Comments are not the place to have an extended discussion about these things.

Comment: @NickBull, unfortunately i could not gather any solid evidence to prove your statement is wrong . So i am choosing your answer as correct... Thanks for helping.. :)

Comment: I have just finished developing a peripheral which does this. Create your own service and put a custom characteristic in it (the peripheral device not the iOS code). When you have your characteristic created, you must discover the services and characteristics. Once discovered you can subscribe to the update events in that characteristic. Now in the device, setup your code to use the notify option (instead of read or write) to send out from the device. And voila! The app wakes up from a terminated state to handle the characteristic update and calls the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` method.